# Maven webapp not working when deployed through mvn tomcat7:deploy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

I'm new to maven spring mvc hibernate archetype. I recently got a source code with same archetype to work on. When I run the project from eclipse option run>run as>local server, it works fine, web site works properly. But for same project when I go for mvn tomcat7:deploy on the same server, the deployment succeeds but i get following error when I open the web site in browser.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.shopping.shopapp.controller.api.MyApiController.myMethod(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;
IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/shopping/shopapp/model/myModel
```

```html
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.shopping.shopapp.api.MyApiController.myMethod(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/shopping/shoapp/model/myModel;
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1259) org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945) org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953) org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620) org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

my pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.shopping</groupId>
  <artifactId>ShopApp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Shop</name>

  <properties>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.30</mysql.connector.version>
    <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.6</slf4j.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.11.Final</hibernate.version>
    <dbcp.version>1.4</dbcp.version>
    <servletapi.version>2.5</servletapi.version>

  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- database pool -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>${dbcp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate ORM -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jgroups</groupId>
      <artifactId>jgroups</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Additional Analyzers: -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-search-analyzers</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Infinispan integration: -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-search-infinispan</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.2.Final</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.jgroups</groupId>
          <artifactId>jgroups</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring + aspects -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ORM integration, e.g Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security JSP Taglib -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jstl for jsp page -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySql Driver -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging, slf4j -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.7</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.9</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>dynamicreports-adhoc</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>dynamicreports-googlecharts</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.windowsazure.storage</groupId>
      <artifactId>microsoft-windowsazure-storage-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>0.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate EHCache API -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <!-- Spring Social Core -->
      <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Social Facebook -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Social Twitter -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Social Web (contains login/signup controllers) -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>Shop</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
          <server>TomcatServer</server>
          <path>/shopapp</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${jdk.version}</source>
          <target>${jdk.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
          <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/Shop/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
              <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
              <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>org.twitter4j</id>
      <name>org.twitter4j</name>
      <url>http://twitter4j.org/maven2/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

</project>
```

My Web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ShopApp</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml, /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.shopping.shopapp.*" />
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/WEB-INF/js/" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/css/" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/fonts/**" location="/WEB-INF/fonts/" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/WEB-INF/img/" />
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
      <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
      <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
    <constructor-arg value="UTF-8" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Stop the server, run `mvn tomcat7:run` does it gives the same Error?

Comment: post the full stack trace

Comment: Thanks for the reply @PeterRader. I tried this but it gets stuck INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]. And i'm not sure but tomcat7:run and eclipse run looks same. Also I can't apply this run method if i want to deploy the project to remote server.

Comment: added full stack trace @localhost999

Comment: thank you for the respone, @question_maven_com, added pom.xml

Comment: Where is this class  : com.api.MyApiController ?

Comment: Sorry, @question_maven_com, updated my code snippet. its In a webservice project folder com/shopping/shopapp/controller/api/

Comment: Your pom is clean, show web.xml and spring mvc configuration ?

Comment: @question_maven_com web.xml added

Comment: add your MyApiController.java file pls

Comment: You have @ModelAttribute like this : "myModel"

Comment: @question_maven_com  Thank you all for the reply but my important doubt is, it runs from direct eclipse run then why not after deploying ?

Comment: anyone got the answer please ? I'm stuck for more than 24 hours now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED the war file created buy mvn commandline was missing java files. So created the war file from Eclipse export option and deployed it. Working fine now